# Is it difficult to determine the upper bound of the rank of the quadratic twist of a given elliptic curve?

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves, arithmetic-geometry

Let $E:y^2=x^3+ax+b$ be a given elliptic curve over $\mathbb{Q}$, and let $D$ be an integer. The quadratic twist of $E$, denoted by $E_D$, is given by the equation $E_D:Dy^2=x^3+ax+b$. A natural question arises: what can be said about the upper bound of $rank(E_D/\mathbb{Q})$? Is it difficult to determine the upper bound of the rank of the quadratic twist of a given elliptic curve?

For instance, when $b=0$ and the 2-torsion points of $E$ are ${(0,0),\infty}$, a result found in Silverman's famous book 'The Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves' states that $rank(E_D/\mathbb{Q})\le 2\omega(2D)-1$, where $\omega(2D)$ denotes the number of prime factors of $2D$.

Comment: "Determining *the* upper bound" – what kind of upper bound are you after (and why are you sure that one exists)? I believe there isn't even a single $E$ for which we know if the set $\{ rank(E_D / \mathbb{Q})$ : D varying $\}$ is finite or not, so there is no hope for an "optimal" bound.

Comment: @David Loeffler. I apologize for the substantial delay in my response, as I took some time to consider the matter myself. If it is still convenient for you, I would like to ask for the professor's opinion on this issue.　　　　I mean, in the case $E(\Bbb{Q})[2]=4$, $rank(E_D/\Bbb{Q})\le 2ω(D)+2ω(Δ_E)+2$. Can we improve this inequality by the inequality that bounds $rank(E_D/\Bbb{Q})$ using $D$ ?